# Finding the radius of convergence with limsup

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

For a power series defined as

$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \end{aligned}a_n\,(z-z_0)^n$

the radius of convergence is equal to

$R = \frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}}$

that, if it exists, is equivalent to

$R = \frac{1}{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}}$

My question then is the following: you might propose to me a power series where the latter limit does not exist and therefore must refer to the strict definition?

Thank you!

Comment: $$a_{2n}=2^n\qquad a_{2n+1}=1$$

Comment: You could just as well have $a_{2n+1}=0$...

Comment: That is not recurrence. It is a sequence that alternates between $1$ and powers of $2$.

Comment: @Manu Please read carefully what is posted to answer your question, before commenting on it.

Comment: The sequence $1,0,1,0,1,0, \dots $ also comes to mind.

Comment: $a_n=(\sin(n))^n$